# MSVC 2010 back and forward navigation toolbar buttons

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, interface, navigation

I just started trying out MSVC-2010 seriously, and discovered 2 critical toolbar buttons I always used are missing: The back and forward navigation buttons, which were present in MSVC 2003 through 2008. These jump back (or forward) through the sequence of locations observed in the code recently. Can anyone tell me how to get these buttons back?

Here are the product miscellanea:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel

Installed Version: VC Express

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010   01013-532-2002287-70195
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see them on the Standard Toolbar:

[image: Standard Toolbar in VS2010]

If for some reason yours have fallen off, you can put them back using Customize. The commands are under Navigate. They are also on the View Menu (Navigate Backwards and Navigate Forwards) and have keyboard shortcuts which are listed on the View Menu.

Comment: In VS 2013, the icons are different, arrows on a dark circle background and are on the very left of the standard toolbar.  I couldn't find them at first.

Answer (score 15):

In Visual C++ 2010 Express, you can restore these and many other menu and toolbar commands by selecting **Tools->Settings->Expert Settings**.

Apparently only experts want to navigate through their code :-)